# Parameters not passing in stack navigator in react native

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I have a stack navigator:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import MainScreen from './../screens/MainScreen';
import ServiceScreen from './../screens/ServiceScreen';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeNavigator(){
    return(
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false
    }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="MainScreen" component={MainScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="ServiceScreen" component={ServiceScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
    );
}

export default HomeNavigator;
```

Now I have this line in a button press event in my `MainScreen`

```
navigation.navigate('ServiceScreen', {location: selectedLocation});
```

Service Screen:
In here, ServiceApi is imported and is an apisauce post function. Also other things like separator and stuff are components I build.

```
function ServiceScreen({location}) {

    console.log(`ServicesScreen ${location}`);

    const [services, setServices] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {getServices()}, []);

    async function getServices(){
        const response = await ServicesApi.getServices();
        setServices(response.data);
    }

    if(!services) {
        return <AppText>No Services available!</AppText>
    }
    return (
        <Screen style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.location}>
                <AppText>{location}</AppText>
            </View>
                <Separator style={styles.separator} />
                <Separator style={styles.bar} />
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                {services.map(service => (
                    <View style={styles.subcat} key={service.id}>
                    <ServiceListItem name={service.name} img={servicePictures[service.img]} distance={service.distance} />
                    { service.id!=services[services.length-1].id && <Separator /> }
                    </View>
                ))}
            </ScrollView>  
        </Screen>
    );
}
```

I am navigated to the ServiceScreen but `location` is `undefined`

Comment: Hey where did you define selectedLocation?

Comment: Yeah so selectedLocation is a string which user will select. I console.log() it before giving it to my navigator. And it has a string name and not undefined.

Comment: Can you provide the code segment of the ServiceScreen.

Comment: call this.props.route.params.location in services screen instead of location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because params passed by navigation can be accessed in `props.route.params`. So in your case it would be:

```js
function ServiceScreen({route}) {

    console.log(`ServicesScreen ${route.params.location}`);
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params

Comment: OK I didn't knew that. I thought they are direct parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `route.params` to read the params which you passed with the navigation inside the navigated screen. In here your ServiceScreen should be as follows.

```html
function ServiceScreen({route}) {

    console.log(`ServicesScreen ${route.params.location}`);

    const [services, setServices] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {getServices()}, []);

    async function getServices(){
        const response = await ServicesApi.getServices();
        setServices(response.data);
    }

    if(!services) {
        return <AppText>No Services available!</AppText>
    }
    return (
        <Screen style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.location}>
                <AppText>{route.params.location}</AppText>
            </View>
                <Separator style={styles.separator} />
                <Separator style={styles.bar} />
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
                {services.map(service => (
                    <View style={styles.subcat} key={service.id}>
                    <ServiceListItem name={service.name} img={servicePictures[service.img]} distance={service.distance} />
                    { service.id!=services[services.length-1].id && <Separator /> }
                    </View>
                ))}
            </ScrollView>  
        </Screen>
    );
}
```